# LdapAuthenticationProvider::authenticate locks account after a single call with wrong password

Tags: spring-security, ldap, jndi, spring-security-ldap

This is/was a java issue see [Retrying a failed authentication on multiple LDAP servers can lead to users blocked](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/6043)

We have an issue with Active Directory/LDAP user accounts becoming locked after doing a single call to LdapAuthenticationProvider::authenticate (spring-security 5.4.2)
when the LDAP URL contains more LDAP servers than the max allowed Bad-Pwd-Count.

The problem does not occur when using jdk1.8.0_252 but it does occur using jdk1.8.0_301 and above. Using tcpdump shows that all LDAP servers contained in the provided LDAP server URL list are being asked to validate the password under jdk1.8.0_301 which locks the account.
The following code demonstrates the problem using rroemhild/test-openldap (see https://github.com/rroemhild/docker-test-openldap). When the code is run with jdk1.8.0_252 the result is a javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials] which is the result we expect. When it is executed under jdk1.8.0_301 the result is a  sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException (this happens because the second LDAP server in the test setup is using an unknown cert - displaying the fact that it has been contacted, which it shouldn’t).

Which behavior is the expected one and how can we avoid user accounts being locked when using jdk1.8.0_301?

To verify the issue do:

```
docker pull rroemhild/test-openldap
docker run --rm -p 10389:10389 -p 10636:10636 rroemhild/test-openldap
tcpdump -i docker0 port 10389 or port 10636
```

And run the following code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@EnableWebSecurity
@WebAppConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
public class LdapAuthOpenLdapTest {

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @WebAppConfiguration
    @EnableWebMvc
    static class LdapSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
            auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthProvider());
        }

        @Bean
        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource ldapServer() {
            DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource result = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(
                    "ldap://localhost:10389 ldaps://localhost:10636");
            result.setUserDn("cn=admin,dc=planetexpress,dc=com");
            result.setPassword("GoodNewsEveryone");
            return result;
        }

        @Bean
        FilterBasedLdapUserSearch userSearch() {
            return new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("dc=planetexpress,dc=com",
                    "(&(uid={0})(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))", ldapServer());
        }

        @Bean
        LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthProvider() {
            BindAuthenticator bindAuthenticator = new BindAuthenticator(
                    ldapServer());
            bindAuthenticator.setUserSearch(userSearch());
            DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator authoritiesPopulator = new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(
                    ldapServer(), "ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com");
            authoritiesPopulator.setGroupRoleAttribute("cn");
            authoritiesPopulator.setRolePrefix("ROLE_");
            authoritiesPopulator.setConvertToUpperCase(true);
            return new LdapAuthenticationProvider(bindAuthenticator,
                    authoritiesPopulator);
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthProvider;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Exception ex = null;
        try {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    "professor", "professor1");
            Authentication auth = ldapAuthProvider.authenticate(token);
            System.out.println(auth);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertThat(ex, is(nullValue()));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is done by the server, not by the client. You're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: user207421 would you mind explaining this a bit more? If this is related to the LDAP servers how come we get different behavior using two different java versions?

Answer (score 0):

LDAP accounts might be blocked even after only one login attempt when connecting using the web user interface or Dynamic Workload Console through LDAP/AD authentication if wrong credentials are provided because of internal LDAP/AD security policy. This happens because one login attempt with wrong credentials using the web user interface or Dynamic Workload Console is transformed into several authentication requests to LDAP.

**Cause and solution:**

When a single LDAP hostname is mapped to multiple IP addresses in a network configuration, if an invalid password is entered during the login, WebSphere makes as many login attempts as the number of associated IP addresses plus 1. If the resulting number exceeds the maximum number of failed logins allowed by the local LDAP/AD security policy, the LDAP account is blocked. In the log file SystemOut.log the following error shows an authentication error because of wrong credentials

Two new custom properties are available to prevent this issue; use the one suitable for your LDAP configuration:

- If LDAP is configured using the wsadminl command to register backend
  LDAP server hostnames, in the administration console click Security >
  User Registries > LDAP > Custom Properties and set to true the
  property com.ibm.websphere.security.ldap.retryBind. If this property
  is set to false, the Application Server does not retry LDAP bind
  calls. The default value is true.
- If LDAP is configured associating a hostname with multiple IP
  addresses using the network configuration, in the administration
  console click Security > User Registries > LDAP > Custom Properties
  and set to false the property
  com.ibm.websphere.security.registry.ldap.singleLDAP. If this property
  is set to true, the Application Server does not resolve an LDAP
  hostname to multiple IP addresses. The default value is false.